# How to take data from one data.frame and put it in another with multiple conditions in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-structures, conditional-statements

I have a bit of a problem to figure out how to do something. I have two data.frame, and i want to take variable to one date.frame and add it to the other with certain conditions. Here an extract of my two data.frame :

Data.frame 1 :

```
ID    YEAR_F
154   2005
432   2005
123   2007
```

Data.frame 2 :

```
ID   Year_D    Month    DC1    DC2

154   2001       1       4      23
154   2001       2       56     22
154   2005       1       32     11 
154   2005       2       12     10
432   2005       1       23     11 
432   2006       1       23     10 
432   2006       2       22     11
123   2001       1       12     34
123   2007       1       11     12
123   2007       2       11     11 
123   2004       1       43     43
```

So i want to take the DC1 and DC2 of the second data.frame and add it to my first data.frame. But, i want it to do it according to the year of the first data.frame. Plus, i want to have a column of DC1 and DC2 by month. So, in final my data.frame will look something like that :

data.frame 3 :

```
ID   Year_D   DC1_M1   DC1_M2     DC2_M1    DC2_M2

154   2005     32         12        11         10
432   2005     23         na        11         na
123   2007     11         11        12         11
```

I'm not really sure how to do it ? Especially because the structure of the second data.frame change ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

We can pivot the second dataset to 'wide' format after `filter`ing based on the 'YEAR_F' of first data and then do a join

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df2 %>% 
  filter(Year_D %in% df1$YEAR_F) %>% 
  select(-Year_D) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Month, values_from = c(DC1, DC2)) %>% 
  right_join(df1) %>%
  select(names(df1), everything())
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
#     ID YEAR_F DC1_1 DC1_2 DC2_1 DC2_2
#  <int>  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1   154   2005    32    12    11    10
#2   432   2005    23    NA    11    NA
#3   123   2007    11    11    12    11
```

---

Or using `base R` with `merge` and `reshape`

```
merge(df1, reshape(subset(df2, Year_D %in% df1$YEAR_F, select = -Year_D), 
       idvar = 'ID', direction = 'wide', timevar = 'Month'))
#   ID YEAR_F DC1.1 DC2.1 DC1.2 DC2.2
#1 123   2007    11    12    11    11
#2 154   2005    32    11    12    10
#3 432   2005    23    11    NA    NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(154L, 432L, 123L), YEAR_F = c(2005L, 2005L, 
2007L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(ID = c(154L, 154L, 154L, 154L, 432L, 432L, 432L, 
123L, 123L, 123L, 123L), Year_D = c(2001L, 2001L, 2005L, 2005L, 
2005L, 2006L, 2006L, 2001L, 2007L, 2007L, 2004L), Month = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), DC1 = c(4L, 56L, 32L, 
12L, 23L, 23L, 22L, 12L, 11L, 11L, 43L), DC2 = c(23L, 22L, 11L, 
10L, 11L, 10L, 11L, 34L, 12L, 11L, 43L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```